# C: Take parts from a string without a delimiter (using strstr)

Tags: c

I have a string, for example: `"Error_*_code_break_*_505_*_7.8"`

I need to split the string with a loop by the delimiter `"_*_"` using the `strstr` function and input all parts into a new array, let's call it -

```
char *elements[4] = {"Error", "code_break", "505", "7.8"}
```

but `strstr` only gives me a pointer to a char, any help?

Note: the second string `"code_break"` should still contain `"_"`, or in any other case.

Comment: This is no coding service. You first have to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you half-way there.  This program prints the split pieces of the string to the standard output; it does not make an array, but maybe you can add that yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void split(const char * str, const char * delimiter)
{
    char * writable_str = strdup(str);
    if (writable_str == NULL) { return; }
    char * remaining = writable_str;
    while (1)
    {
        char * ending = strstr(remaining, delimiter);
        if (ending != NULL) { *ending = 0; }
        printf("%s\n", remaining);
        if (ending == NULL) { break; }
        remaining = ending + strlen(delimiter);
    }
    free(writable_str);
}

int main(void) {
    const char * str = "Error_*_code_break_*_505_*_7.8";
    const char * delimiter = "_*_";
    split(str, delimiter);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that splits a string into an array.  You have to pass the size of the array so that the function won't overfill it.  It returns the number of things it put into the array.  What it puts into the array is a pointer into the string that was passed.  It modifies the string by inserting null characters to end the pieces - just like strtok does.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int split(char *string, char *delimiter, char* array[], int size)
{
    int count=0;
    char *current=string;
    char *next;
    while(current && *current!='\0')
    {
         next=strstr(current,delimiter);
         if(!next)break;
         *next='\0';
         if(count<size) array[count++]=current;
         current=next+strlen(delimiter);
    }
    if(count<size) array[count++]=current;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    char string[100]="Error_*_code_break_*_505_*_7.8";
    char *array[10];
    int size=split(string,"_*_",array,10);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) puts(array[i]);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So true! I do actually know what I am doing so I'm not sure what was I thinking?